# Efficiently finding an element in in an array where consecutive elements differ by +1/0/-1

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I have this problem, that I feel I am vastly overcomplicating. I feel like this should be incredibly basic, but I am stumbling on a mental block.

The question reads as follows:

> Given an array of integers A[1..n], such that A[1] ≤ A[n] and for all
> i, 1 ≤ i < n, we have |A[i] − A[i+ 1]| ≤ 1. Devise an semi-efficient
> algorithm (better in the worst case then the native case of looking at
> every cell in the array) to find any j such that A[j] = z for a given
> value of z, A[1] ≤ z ≤ A[n].

My understanding of the given array is as follows: You have an array that is 1-indexed where the first element of the array is smaller than or equal to the last element of the array. Each element of the array is with in 1 of the previous one (So A[2] could be -1, 0, or +1 of A[1]'s value).

I have had several solutions to this question all of which have had there issues, here is an example of one to show my thought process.

```
i = 2
while i <= n {
    if (A[i] == x) then 
        break // This can be changed into a less messy case where
              // I don't use break, but this is a rough concept
    else if (abs(A[i] - j) <= 1) then 
        i--
    else 
        i += 2

}
```

This however fails when most of the values inside the array are repeating.
An array of `[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2]` where searching for 2 for example, it would run forever.

Most of my attempted algorithms follow a similar concept of incrementing by 2, as that seems like the most logical approach when dealing with with an array that is increasing by a maximum of 1, however, I am struggling to find any that would work in a case such as `[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2]` as they all either fail, or match the native worst case of n.

I am unsure if I am struggling because I don't understand what the question is asking, or if I am simply struggling to to put together an algorithm.

What would an algorithm look like that fits the requirements?

Comment: It would look like binary search. There is really not much choice for search algorithm that is better than O(n)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov the array is not sorted, so I don't think this is binary search

Comment: BTW, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code

Comment: @JohnSmithson While this isn't sorted, binary search will always select the half with the target, so will find it in log time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be solved via a form of modified binary search. The most important premises:

- the input array always contains the element
- distance between adjacent elements is always 1
- there's always an increasingly ordered subarray containing the searched value

Taking it from there we can apply two strategies:

- divide and conquer: we can reduce the range searched by half, since we always know which subarray will definitely contain the specified value as a part of an increasing sequence.
- limiting the search-range: suppose the searched value is 3 and the limiting value on the right half of the range is 6, we can then shift the right limit to the left by 3 cells.

As code (pythonesque, but untested):

```
def search_semi_binary(arr, val):
    low, up = 0, len(arr) - 1
    while low != up:
        # reduce search space
        low += abs(val - arr[low])
        up -= abs(val - arr[up])

        # binary search
        mid = (low + up) // 2

        if arr[mid] == val:
            return mid
        elif val < arr[mid]:
            # value is definitely in the lower part of the array
            up = mid - 1
        else:
            # value is definitely in the upper part of the array
            low = mid + 1

    return low
```

The basic idea consists of two parts:
First we can reduce the search space. This uses the fact that adjacent cells of the array may only differ by one. I.e. if the lower bound of our search space has an absolute difference of 3 to `val`, we can shift the lower bound to the right by at least three without shifting the value out of the search window. Same applies to the upper bound.
The next step follows the basic principle of binary search using the following loop-invariant:
At the start of each iteration there exists an array-element in `arr[low:up + 1]` that is equal to `val` and `arr[low] <= val <= arr[up]`. This is also guaranteed after applying the search-space reduction. Depending on how `mid` is chosen, one of three cases can happen:

- `arr[mid] == val`: in this case, the searched index is found
- `arr[mid] < val`: In this case `arr[mid] < val <= arr[up]` must hold due to the assumption of an initial valid state
- `arr[mid] > val`: analogous for `arr[mid] > val >= arr[low]`

For the latter two cases, we can pick `low = mid + 1` (or `up = mid - 1` respectively) and start the next iteration.

Comment: Well I had found another problem case but your edit seems to have fixed that. So it comes down to whether the meaning is that you look at less distinct elements in the array or less total elements. This sometimes looks at more total elements than are in the array but definitely fewer distinct ones. I'm assuming they mean distinct, so this is definitely best.

Comment: @Nick even short of a specific requirement, this code should outperform anything that was posted here so far. The first part of each iteration follows pretty much the same idea as the other algorithms. The advantage of binary search will show up once arrays get bigger, but for small arrays it's a bit of a gamble. In fact the first part of the loop could be ommitted, reducing the total effort to one "look" per iteration.

Comment: Indeed. I was struggling to get my head around using binary search with an array that was not completely sorted but I guess it is sorted "enough" that the tests still work thanks to the `A[1] ≤ z ≤ A[n]` constraint

Comment: @Paul This solution is still `O(n)` (not `O(logn)`) where n is the amount of elements in the array since it depends on the values of the array. An example: it could be the case that all positions except one are zeroes and you are searching for a position with a 1, gnasher729 explained that in such case every devised algorithm is `Ω(n)` at worst case escenario which expose that the requirements of the problem are explicitly made to find wrong answers. I suppose this is homework assignment.

Comment: Apparently the requirements stipulate that the 1 would have to be at the last index though.

Comment: @ggorlen they do, so gnasher729's answer is incorrect, and this solution will find the index in `O(logn)`

Comment: @EloyPérezTorres as far as gnashers answer is concerned, it misses out on the constraint `A[1] <= z <= A[n]`, which makes the condition prior to the discussion already malformed. And it's definitely `O(log n)`, since this whole answer is basically a binary search with a few tweaks.

Comment: @Paul +1 for binary search, though there are cases where the step to 'reduce the search space' slows this down. E.g., find a lone one in an array with many zeroes & twos.

Comment: @Dave in that scenario it doesn't add any value. On the other hand there's quite a few possible cases, where the reduction may actually be the part contributing more to the overall performance than the binary search. In general those two extra operations shouldn't harm performance too much, but it's a trade off based on guesswork without actually knowing the statistical properties of the input.

Answer (score 1):

In the worst case, you'll have to look at all array elements.

Assume all elements are zero, except that a[k] = 1 for one single k, 1 ≤ k ≤ n. k isn't known, obviously. And you look for the value 1. Until you visit a[k], whatever you visit has a value of 0. Any element that you haven't visited could be equal to 1.

Comment: This is not true, given the constraints of the question, the only way that scenario can be valid is if the `1` is the last element of the array, and @Paul solution will find that in `O(log n)`

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we are looking for a number 5. If they array starts with A[1]=1, the best case scenario is having the 5 in A[5] as it needs to be incremented at least 4 times. If A[5] = 3, then let's check A[7] as it's the closest possible solution. How do we decide it's A[7]? From the number we are looking for, let's call it R for result, we subtract what we currently have, let's call it C for current, and add the result to i as in A[i+(R-C)]

Unfortunately the above solution would apply to every scenario but the worst case scenario (when we iterate through the whole array).

Comment: `A[1] ≤ A[n]` only means the first element is less than or equal to the last element (are they 1-indexing? sigh). That doesn't guarantee the next value of `A[i]` for any `i` cannot be lower than `A[i-1]`. `[1, 2, 1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 2]` seems like a perfectly valid array per the problem constraints, no? Nonetheless, I think what you're suggesting in the bottom paragraph makes sense: if you're looking for 4 and you're at an element containing 2, then we can skip the next element. If that element turns out to be 0 then skip 3 elements ahead, etc. But I don't think it helps the worst case.

Comment: Sorry for the edit, didn't see your answer. Either way, the same logic applies. If value can change only by 1 you can estimate how far away within the array the closest solution could be and check for it.

Comment: This problem is A[1], not A[i].

Comment: If I am not mistaken this also runs into an issue when using the array of [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2]. As it starts at both i = 1, and the value 1. It checks and finds that i = 2 is the next possible solution, then i = 3 and so forth, and it checks every element of the array.

Comment: You are right, the questions clearly states "better in the worst case then the native case of looking at every cell in the array". We could compare A[N] at the beginning as well to avoid this.

Comment: If you were looking for `2` in `[1 1 1 2 3]` this would still look at every element in the array.